# Postgresql order records by string pattern

Tags: postgresql, sorting, pattern-matching, sql-order-by

Let's say we have products with title, position and source.

http://rextester.com/live/TCFOBJ26312

I need to order the products by string pattern 'basse'.
After order products should look like:

```
id  title   source  position
9   prod 9  b   0
1   prod 1  a   0
13  prod 13 s   0
14  prod 14 s   1
5   prod 5  e   0
10  prod 10 b   1
2   prod 2  a   1
15  prod 15 s   2
16  prod 16 s   3
6   prod 6  e   1
11  prod 11 b   2
3   prod 3  a   2
7   prod 7  e   2
12  prod 12 b   3
4   prod 4  a   3
8   prod 8  e   3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select id, title, source, position
from (
    select id, title, source, position, new_source,
        case new_source
            when 'b' then 0
            when 'a' then 1
            when 's' then 2
            when 't' then 3
            else 4
        end as pos
    from (
        select id, title, source, position,
            case 
                when source <> 's' then source
                when (row_number() over w % 2)::int::bool then 's'
                else 't'
            end as new_source
        from products
        window w as (partition by source order by position)
        ) s
    ) s
window w as (partition by new_source order by position)
order by (row_number() over w)* 5+ pos;
```

[Test it here.](http://rextester.com/KPAE78631)

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to achieve this just by sorting. Instead, create a PL/pgSQL function "basse()" which returns a setof record.
Inside the function, declare four unbound arrays of product%rowtype for b,a,s,e and open a cursor to iterate over products.
Put each read product in its corresponding array.
Then intercalate the arrays returning one element from the proper array (if not empty). Finally call RETURN at the end of the function.
For using the function, do SELECT * FROM basse()